# iOS8 automatic tableviewheight wrong on first cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, size-classes

I'm using Autolayout on iOS 8 and make use of UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic and all of its magic.

When the Tableview appears the cells have a wrong height and the subviews are distributed over the whole cell with a lot of horizontal space between them. When I scroll down or rotate the device and back alls cells are drawn correctly with the correct size.
Debugger says no error and  Autolayout warnings are not present.

These cells are only drawn on iPad and I have specified only for sizeclass (Regular | Regular).

Do you any hints what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you implemented the `estimatedHeightForRow...` method? And what is your code for `heightForRow...`? You need both of these methods before auto layout height will work.

Comment: Yes I did:   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic; the heightForRow is not implemented because it wouldn't be needed anymore as I read in a tutorial

Comment: No, that is not correct. I'll add an answer...

Comment: Also, you are using the wrong constant. You need `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` not `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things that you need to make sure you are doing...

1. The AutoLayout Constraints should cover the entire height of the cell. So just by looking at the constraints you should be able to say exactly how tall the cell is.
2. Implement the estimated height for row method...

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       // return an actual number here. This is a guess of how tall the cells are
       return 100;
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   // Thanks @rdelmar :-)
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
   ```
3. Implements height for row...

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       // return auto dimension here
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }
   ```

Once you have done all three of these it will work.

See my blog here for more data (note, there has been an update since I wrote the blog which I haven't updated yet).

http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: I changed it to this and the behavior is exactly as bevor.... Could it be the (regular|regular) thing?

Comment: Are you running on iPad or iPhone? Regular|regular is for iPad only. If you're using Size Classes then keep it simple by not changing it ever. You'll need to put it back to Any|Any but the chances are that the constraints that you have added will be on Regular|Regular. Easiest solution to fix this... delete the nib file and start again.

Comment: Also, how are you presenting the view? Is it in a pop over? Or is it the entire screen? Or is in in a split view controller?

Comment: I'm running on an iPad in fullscreen and not in a popover or splitview.

Comment: Please show your code in your question. (Edit the question don't put code in a comment). And a screenshot of your nib. Just to check what's going on.

Comment: Since when does `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;` not work? Is this a change from what was originally described in the WWDC video? In the video, they don't implement either method, they just set the properties.

Comment: Please show your code in your question. (Edit the question don't put code in a comment). And a screenshot of your nib. Just to check what's going on.

Comment: @rdelmar no idea when it happened. All I know is that the code in my blog doesn't work unless I implement that method. Setting the property doesn't seem to have an effect any more.

Comment: I just tested one of my programs in iOS 8.3 (Xcode 6.3.1), and setting rowHeight (to UITableViewAutomaticDimension) and estimatedRowHeight in viewDidLoad worked fine as long as I added a call to `layoutIfNeeded` in `didMoveToSuperview` in the custom cell class. I had found previously that I needed to do that for cells created in the storyboard, but not if I added the subviews and constraints in code.

Comment: Ah. Maybe it's the layoutifneeded call that's missing. Strange though that you run it in viewdidload which runs before layout is done anyway.

Comment: I put it in viewDidLoad because that's what they showed in the WWDC video. I don't know if there's anywhere else you could put those 2 lines that would work any better (it doesn't in viewDidAppear).

Comment: @rdelmar yeah. That's where it is in my code too. You can see it on GitHub. Oh well.

Comment: @rdelmar ignore me. I don't even have that code in. Never mind, it's been a long day. That was the change though. Previously you didn't need that code at all. Anyway, time for a drink I think. lol!n Either way, setting it to `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` definitely will not work. :D